# how to generate random text with variable in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I know how to generate random text in jinja2, but is there a way I can put variables in the random text options. Something like that:

```
{{ [
"{{ variable1 }} and other text ",
"{{ variable2 }} and other text"
] | random }}
```

The problem is if I write this way, `{{ variable1 }}` and `{{ variable2 }}` would be rendered as pure text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your strings to not include the verbatim name of the variable and do some string appending instead.

For example:

```
{{ [
variable1 + " and other text ",
variable2 + " and other text"
] | random }}
```

You're already in a template section, so you don't need to escape the variable declarations.